# Connecting an Ultrasonic Sensor to Arduino (4-Wire)

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an ultrasonic sensor that came with a couple of images about the pin-out and wiring diagram.

I am used to the popular ultrasonic sensors that have lots of documentation about how to connect to an Arduino - but I am wondering about to connect this sensor to an Arduino.

The Power Supply is 5V DC, with an operating current less than or equal to 12mA.

Any support or similar tutorials that will help me connect this to an Arduino, to see the output in the Serial monitor, would be great!

VCC and GND are self-explanatory, but how should I connect the Output 1 and Output 2 to the Arduino?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: First, identify the sensor, and where you found. A snapshot would help as well.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultrasonic-Range-detector-using-Arduino-and-the-SR/